# How to make the correct output?

Tags: python, string

The requirment of the code is :
There is a txt file called "lts_en_us_12.9.0_phonRules_Default copy.txt" in which is a bunch of phonology rules such as follows. (I showed the first several rows of the file).

```
word {. .} {{;}} {rewrite}
word {{#} .} {{$0} {;}} {rewrite}
word {{;} .} {{$0} {;}} {rewrite}
word {.pau .} {{$0} {;}} {rewrite}
word {. #} {{;} {$1}} {rewrite}
word {. {;}} {{;} {$1}} {rewrite}
word {. .pau} {{;} {$1}} {rewrite}
word {{;} {;}} {{;}} {rewrite}
aux-verb-reduction {{;} k aI1 n d {;} {^1 &} v {;}} {{$0} k aI1 n . d & {$8}} {optional}
aux-verb-reduction {{;} w A1 n t {;} t {u1 &} {;}} {{$0} w A1 . n & {$8}} {optional}
aux-verb-reduction {{;} l E1 t {;} m i1 {;}} {{$0} l E1 . m i {$7}} {optional}
aux-verb-reduction {{;} g I1 v {;} m i1 {;}} {{$0} g I1 . m i {$7}} {optional}
```

Our goal is to build a txt file called symbols.txt file. This could be done by iterating over the set of phonology rules, and keeping a running list of every symbol that occurs in them. For instance if the rules are just

```
{aspiration} {; k} {; k_h} {rewrite}
{low_vowel} {A} {@} {optional}
{unreleased} {b} {b_c} {rewrite}
```

then the symbols file would be

```
ε 0 
. 1 
@ 2 
A 3 
b 4 
b_c 5 
k 6 
k_h 7
```

Note the top 2 lines here: the epsilon and the . are going to be included at the top, regardless. These are default symbols, whether or not they ever occur in the rules, and have to be included in your symbols.txt.

So to be specific of the true file, the expected output should be:

```
ε 0 
. 1 
. .2
; 3
# . 4
# ; 5 # (Note : the second pound key in this line is a comment.)where "$0" becomes the "#" because dollar sign means replace the i'th element in the left {} into the position where the dollar sign sits. In this case, "$0" means replace the 0th element in the left to the position of "$0". 
; . 6
; .7
. pau . 8
. ; 9
. # 10
; # 11
. ; 12
; ; 13
. .pau 14
; . 15
```

I am new to cs and coding, so I asked Chatgpt3 to help and here is the code Chatgpt3 generated:

```
symbols = [("ε", 0), (".", 1)]
with open("lts_en_us_12.9.0_phonRules_Default copy.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.strip().split(" ")
        for part in parts:
            if part not in [s[0] for s in symbols]:
                symbols.append((part, len(symbols)))

with open("symbols.txt", "w") as f:
    for symbol in symbols:
        f.write(f"{symbol[0]} {symbol[1]}\n")
```

But the probem is that the output of ChatGpt3's code is:

```
ε 0
. 1
word 2
{. 3
.} 4
{{;}} 5
{rewrite} 6
{{#} 7
{{$0} 8
{;}} 9
{{;} 10
{.pau 11
#} 12
{$1}} 13
.pau} 14
aux-verb-reduction 15
k 16
aI1 17
n 18
d 19
```

Which is so different from the expected code based on the requirement. To be pecific, we don't want the "word" and the "rewrite". We just want the output which is from the middle two parts, not the first part and the last part. In addition, we want to list the output in an alphabetic indexing order as in the example output.

So, how could I do that? Or how can I edit this version of the code to fulfill that code requirement and the goal?

Comment: (1) How is this related to TCL? (2) It isn't related to regex groups in particular but to regex in general. (3) The question is too broad because it needs to implement multiple rules to find the symbols.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1 - note that this applies to questions as well as answers.

Comment: Where do `word` and `aux-verb-reduction` even come from? I don't see them in any of your example inputs nor in the code. Also your topic is very speicifc, most of us do not have the knowledge in phonological rules, therefore it may be a good idea to explain it a bit more.

Comment: Hi! `word` and `aux-verb-reduction` are from the actual files which is called `lts_en_us_12.9.0_phonRules_Default copy.txt` that we want to convert. I have edited the question post and added several first lines of the actual file as well as the expected output. Thank you for asking this question!

Comment: @ColinMacleod but the actual question text is human generated and reasonable, so I think it is allowed

Comment: Hi Colin, thank you for telling me the ban of Chatgpt, I I won't put chatgpt content in it next time!

Comment: Hi Michael! This is related to TCL because the content in the file that we want to convert is written in TCL. So I though it would be related to TCL,but now I think I'm wrong. Sorry, I just editted it to remove the tag of TCL.

Comment: As mentioned by several others before most of us aren't familiar with the problem domain. For example how is your symbol file ordered? Is it in alphabetical order? Also from the line `{aspiration} {; k} {; k_h} {rewrite}` why is only `k` and `k_h` in the output? Why are the semicolons not taken as they seem to be in your expected output for the true file? Also you should break your problem down into pieces, the first part should be parsing your phonology rules file (which can be broken down into parsing a single line of the file and iteratively parsing all) and then creating your symbol file

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).